# Disabled button indicates disability but accept click

Tags: javascript, html, css

After I have disabled any button by clicking on it, the button looks like it's disabled but accepts more clicks. I have noted that there is no `<form>` in the page, but adding a `<form>` does not seem to matter.

https://jsfiddle.net/3y1dn29v/

Why?

```js
function tally(card, suit) {
  cards += card;
  suits += suit;
  alert("btn" + card + suit);
  disableButton("btn" + card + suit)
}

function disableButton(button) {
  document.getElementById(button).setAttribute("class", "button disabled");
  var x = document.getElementById(button).getAttribute("class");
  alert(x);
}

var suits = "";
var cards = "";
```

```css
.button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div id="Spades" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>&spades;</h3>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="btnAS" class="button" onclick='tally("A","S")'>A</button>
    <button id="btnKS" class="button" onclick='tally("K","S")'>K</button>
    <button id="btnQS" class="button" onclick='tally("Q","S")'>Q</button>
    <button id="btnJS" class="button" onclick='tally("J","S")'>J</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WHy? because you simply - nowhere in your code set the clicked button to have the `disabled` **attribute**.

Comment: Yes, I did in the function `disableButton()`. Actually if you remove the "button" from the class, you get the same result.

Comment: No. You did not :) there's a huge difference in having  a **cursor style** `not-allowed` and an actually **disabled** button. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button or a quick Goog: "html js how to make button disabled" would lead you to the proper solution.

Comment: The good news is that the "Run code snippet" behaves as I would like. The bad new is two-fold: 1) I don't know how that snippet is implemented and whether there is any CSS input or not, and 2) I don't see any change in what I submitted, including the lacking setting of "... the clicked button to have the `disabled` **attribute**. Could you clarify those 2 bad news, pls?

Comment: I see the CSS now. Sorry, I don't know how I missed it before. But I still see no evidence that the button ha had disabled added in the "Run code snippet". Rather it looks like no change was made from my original post.

Comment: It's simple, you should look closer, in JS I use `that.disabled` where `disabled` is a Property. In CSS I don't use a class (like you do) but rather I target the property-disabled element using the **pseudo-class** `:disabled` (notice the `:`  colon?!) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled

Comment: Aha, sorry for adding the [Run Code Snippet] but it's just for the sake of simplicity (when possible - one should not leave StackOverflow to go to external sites in order to preview your issue - so yeah there's no change in code - just the snippet with your exact original code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, pass the `this` reference and use the `disabled` property both in JS and CSS.

```js
var cards = "",
    suits = "";

function tally(that, card, suit) {
  cards += card;
  suits += suit;
  that.disabled = true;                             // Tyadaaaa ♪
  console.log("CARDS: "+ cards, "SUITS: "+ suits);
}
```

```css
button:disabled {             /* // Tyadaaaa ♪ */
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div id="Spades" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>&spades;</h3>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button onclick='tally(this, "A","S")'>A</button>
    <button onclick='tally(this, "K","S")'>K</button>
    <button onclick='tally(this, "Q","S")'>Q</button>
    <button onclick='tally(this, "J","S")'>J</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;
```

hope this helps

Comment: Wouldn't you want to set it to `true`?

Comment: @bejado Yes. Thank you for pointing out, i ll edit my answer.

Comment: `document.getElementById("Button")` ? why not simply `this`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just tried to give a generalized answer. You can definitely try "this"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the disabled attribute to true

```
     function disableButton(button) {
     document.getElementById(button).setAttribute("class", "button disabled");
     var x = document.getElementById(button).getAttribute("class");
     alert(x);
     document.getElementById(button).disabled = true;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work, mostly. But on my *real* page it seems to block the little ghostbuster tooltip, so I need to recover that too. I hope I have time.

Answer (score -1):

add `pointer-events: none;` to your `.disabled` CSS

Comment: Note that IE 8 does not support `pointer-events` http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: Luckily IE8 is 1% market share (probably North Corea...) @bejado

Answer (score -1):

```js
    function tally(btn, card, suit) {
      if(btn.disabled){
        console.log(btn);
         btn.preventDefault();
         return;
      }
      cards += card;
      suits += suit;
      alert("btn" + card + suit);
      disableButton("btn" + card + suit)
    }

    function disableButton(button) {
      document.getElementById(button).setAttribute("class", "button disabled");
      var x = document.getElementById(button).getAttribute("class");
      alert(x);
    }

    var suits = "";
    var cards = "";
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

I added the button reference in the onClick function call in the html.
And in the JavaScript you can leverage that reference and check if the button has the disabled attribute set to true.

```js
function tally(btn, card, suit) {
  if(btn.disabled)
    return;
  cards += card;
  suits += suit;
  alert("btn" + card + suit);
  disableButton("btn" + card + suit)
}

function disableButton(button) {
  document.getElementById(button).setAttribute("class", "button disabled");
  document.getElementById(button).setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  var x = document.getElementById(button).getAttribute("class");
  alert(x);
}

var suits = "";
var cards = "";
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div id="Spades" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>&spades;</h3>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button id="btnAS" class="button" onclick='tally(this, "A","S")'>A</button>
      <button id="btnKS" class="button" onclick='tally(this, "K","S")'>K</button>
      <button id="btnQS" class="button" onclick='tally(this, "Q","S")'>Q</button>
      <button id="btnJS" class="button" onclick='tally(this, "J","S")'>J</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your idea was promising, but it does not change the result: I can still click on the button again and again, getting a response each time,

Comment: I forgot to try preventDefault

Comment: I fixed it by adding the following: 
document.getElementById(button).setAttribute("disabled", "true");